# Comparison Operators for Class Objects (not instances)

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my current project I found it clearer and more logical to declare Subclasses (similar to Django's `Model` syntax) rather than creating instances of the base object. On the premise of keeping it simple to read, I also wanted to add comparators to the parent class. Here is a simple example to clarify the situation:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Version():
    VERSIONNUMBER = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try: ## catch issubclass(instance, Version)
            if issubclass(other, Version): return self.VERSIONNUMBER == other.VERSIONNUMBER
        except TypeError: pass
        return NotImplemented

    def __lt__(self, other):
        try:
            if issubclass(other, Version): return self.VERSIONNUMBER < other.VERSIONNUMBER
        except TypeError: pass
        return NotImplemented

class Version1(Version):
    VERSIONNUMBER = 1.0

class Version2(Version):
    VERSIONNUMBER = 2.0

assert Version2 > Version1
```

This, however, throws `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'type'`.

**Things I've tried**

Upon reflection, I understand this means that the rich comparison methods are being called from `type` (which `object`/class is an instance of), so a simple fix like adding the `classmethod` decorator to the comparison methods doesn't do anything. Making an `Orderable` super class is obviously out as well since that would simply be another instance of `type` and therefore `type`'s comparitors would still be called. I don't think this is something that could be implemented with a `metaclass`, but I'm not fluent enough in them to say that with absolute certainty.

My searches generally returned irrelevant topics:

- "TypeError [etc]" returns all the generic " '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int' " style questions (even when including quotes around "Type and Type")
- Various forms of "Compare Class Objects" return questions about comparing *instances* rather than the Class Objects themselves
- I tried things along the lines of "Compare/Order/Sort Types", but again no relevant info
- I poked around Django's github inside `django.db.models` but didn't notice any implementations in the files I checked (I'll admit I could have missed it, since django is a large package)
- Checked the `types` module, but it doesn't seem to do what I need (unless I misread it)

For the time being I can work around it in code by writing `Version2.VERSIONNUMBER > Version1.VERSIONNUMBER`, but I'm really curious how it could be implemented (since it has been my experience that you can do just about anything in Python). My assumption is that the class would have to be constructed using an `object` subtype, I'm just not sure where to begin with that.

Comment: How is `class Version1(Version): VERSIONUMBER = 1.0` simpler to read than `Version1 = Version(1.0)`? Just use instances instead of subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: Off the top of my head, I'm not sure if you will be able to get `total_ordering` to play well here.

But one method to get the comparison methods to work on a class is to use a meta class rather inheriting them from a parent. For example:

```
class Version_Meta(type):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.VERSIONNUMBER == other.VERSIONNUMBER
        except TypeError: pass
        return NotImplemented

    def __lt__(self,other):
        try:
            return self.VERSIONNUMBER < other.VERSIONNUMBER
        except TypeError: pass
        return NotImplemented

class Version(metaclass=Version_Meta):
    VERSIONNUMBER = None
    
class Version1(Version):
    VERSIONNUMBER = 1.0

class Version2(Version):
    VERSIONNUMBER = 2.0

Version1 < Version2
# True

Version2 < Version1
# False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! `total_ordering` throws an error saying it's missing an argument when you make the comparison (`V1<V2`), but it's trivial to add the other comparators anyway so it's not a problem in my case.